# Did the Arabic IDF page on Facebook say "it was decided to bomb the Baptist Hospital in Gaza and give them euthanasia death"?

Tags: israel, israel-hamas-war

[From Lowkey](https://web.archive.org/web/20231017211030/https://twitter.com/Lowkey0nline/status/1714375248231968952),

[image: Supposed IDF tweet, Due to the lack of medical equipment and the lack of a medical staff, it was decided to bomb the Baptist Hospital in Gaza and give them euthanasia death]

The translation reads,

> Due to the lack of medical equipment and the lack of a medical staff, it was decided to bomb the Baptist Hospital in Gaza and give them euthanasia death

Was this message ever put out?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149177/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-did-the-arabic-idf-page-on-facebook-say); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: After this was ridiculed in some MSM they've deleted the tweet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is not a real post.

The IDF Arabic official Spokesperson is Avichay Adraee, who can be found on Facebook at https://www.facebook.com/IDFarabicAvichayAdraee. The "idfinarabic@gmail.com" email address that has been shared as belonging to the Arabic IDF page comes from that page, and a Google search finds no other results for that email address.

No news reports of the IDF making statements in Arabic points to such a Facebook page - see for instance [this Times of Israel article](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/idf-spokesperson-in-arabic-warns-gaza-residents-to-seek-shelter/) from October 8th, 2023, pointing to Avichay Adraee as the Arabic Spokesperson and not an IDF Arabic page.

The profile image used in the screenshot is the symbol of the [IDF Spokesperson's Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDF_Spokesperson%27s_Unit), but official IDF accounts in various languages - such as their [Hebrew Facebook account](https://www.facebook.com/tzahalonline), their [English Facebook account](https://www.facebook.com/idfonline), and their [Farsi Twitter account](https://twitter.com/IDFFarsi) - all use the main IDF logo as their profile image. The account / page title in the screenshot says "IDF in Arabic" (at least in the Hebrew, I can't read the Arabic), not "IDF Spokesperson's Unit in Arabic". If such an IDF Arabic Facebook account did exist, it would also use the primary IDF symbol as its profile image.

Comment: FWTW, the IDF did launch a Facebook page in Arabic, in 2011 https://www.idf.il/en/mini-sites/our-soldiers/salam-aleykum-facebook/ It's not terribly clear from that if it was different from Avichay Adaree's page though. He is credited with founding the various Arabic pages of the IDF (on Twitter too).

Comment: @Fizz - That screenshot is of Avichay Adraee's page, which I linked in the answer.

Comment: I suppose if they did launch a different page, it would have made no sense to include just a screenshot of Avichay Adaree's page in that announcement.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a mock/fake post, as:

- The question of who bombed the Muatamid/Al-Ahli is in [clear dispute](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/18/media/gaza-hospital-bombing-dueling-claims/index.html), with the Israeli military strongly denying it.
- The Israeli military never claims to perform "mercy killings" of Palestinians; it claims it does not target civilians, and that their deaths by its attacks are accidental/unfortunate. So, the claim in this message is a facetious / macabre-humoristic statement.

<sub>Just to be clear - I don't *buy* the Israeli military's claims; but that's beside the point.</sub>

Comment: I think this whole post is besides the point. Whether or not you find it clearly a mock or fake post doesn't make this a valid answer on the site. You can question the topic itself in the comments above. The archive.org link above has 16k reposts, so apparently many of us didn't find it so clear. And it doesn't matter who bombed  the hospital. It matters whether or not the IDF said this. And it doesn't matter what _else_ the IDF said, and when they said it. Only whether or not they said this.

Comment: But since then all hospitals in Gaza have been bombed by the IDF??

Comment: @zzawaideh: Indeed, most of them have. But I'm not sure what you're asking me.